# How to enable ILOGV statements in the Android source code?

Tags: android, dalvik

In `Android 4.3` according to the [source code documentation](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/dalvik/vm/mterp/), the Dalvik interpreter is located in `dalvik/vm/mterp/`. But how can I enable the ILOGV statements so I can see the interpreted byte code in **assembly code at runtime**?

For example, in the [InterpC-portable.cpp line #1185](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/dalvik/vm/mterp/out/InterpC-portable.cpp#1185), it seems that the **assembly code** for the **move opcode (byte code)** is in the ILOGV statement:

```
ILOGV("|move%s v%d,v%d %s(v%d=0x%08x)",(INST_INST(inst) == OP_MOVE) ? "" : "-object", vdst, vsrc1,
kSpacing, vdst, GET_REGISTER(vsrc1));
```

I just need to enable the ILOGV statement to print its content. By default, ILOGV statements are
disabled in the Android source code and I need to enable them.

**Update1:**

The above code seems to print bytecode but not assembly language code or machine language code. Where to the put the print statement in the Android source code to print the interpreted bytecode (assembly language code or machine language code) just before the CPU executes it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? If all you want to do is to see the bytecode of an application, you can use a disassembler like baksmali on the apk.

Comment: I need to see the **assembly code** of the interpreted byte code.

Comment: But why? :) What is it you're actually trying to accomplish? An interpreter doesn't compile the bytecode to machine code -- it's essentially just a big switch statement that executes some code when it encounters an instruction. If you want to see the arm-specific (or x86-specific) implementation of each instruction, you can do that by looking at the dalvik source - there's no need to try to dump it at runtime. Or are you wanting to dump the code that dalvik's JIT compiler generates?

Comment: Please check my updated question. I need to dump the **assembly code** of the interpreted byte code **at runtime** for some purposes.

Comment: Your usage of the term "assembly code" isn't very clear. In this context "assembly code" could refer to the textual representation of either dalvik bytecode or of the arm/x86 machine code. Based on your updated question, it looks like you're interested in the dalvik bytecode.

Comment: **assembly code** = the assembly language code that I think is generated by the interpreter when it interprets dalvik bytecode to assembly language code. I need to see the assembly language code or arm/x86 machine code that is generated by the interpreter just before the CPU execute them.

Comment: But what you are talking about printing out is the dalvik bytecode, not the machine code. And the interpreter doesn't generate any machine code. There is the JIT compiler, which does compile bytecode to machine code, but that's a different beast.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is the problem with asking a very specific question like this without providing context. You're asking about the details on how to do a very specific thing that you think is going to solve your problem, instead of asking about the actual problem you're trying to solve. My goal with the "what are you actually trying to accomplish" questions was to get more context, so I could avoid wasting time trying to answer a question that turned out to be useless to you, because you were asking the wrong thing.

Comment: But when I only used the portable C interpreter and disabled the JIT in Android emulator, I can run apps normally, that means the portable C interpreter generates machine code in somehow, **otherwise how to explain the running of apps on an Android emulator using only the portable C interpreter with disabled JIT.**

Comment: **Here is the context:** I have a patched Android Dalvik system source code lest's call it XYZ that also patches any app **just before executing its instructions on the CPU** (XYZ does not patch the bytecode). I need to add a flag statement during compile time of XYZ such as a=0x0123456789 and b=0x9876543210 before and after every single patch statement XYZ injects in the machine code of an app. Then I need to compute at runtime the CPU execution time overhead that is added by XYZ. Therefore, the ultimate goal is to calculate the CPU execution time overhead added by XYZ to any app execution.

Comment: The compiler generates machine code from the portable C implementation of each instruction at compile time. The interpreter then runs the machine code that the compiler generated for a particular instruction. The interpreter itself doesn't generate code.

Comment: **Which compiler? The JIT compiler is disabled!** Can you please be more specific and put a link to the compiler that is used by the portable C interpreter to produce the machine code? I'm only using the portable C interpreter and the JIT compiler is disabled.

Comment: The compiler that compiles dalvik when you build Android.

Comment: Ok. Where in Android source code can I print the machine code just before my app executes its instruction on the CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable those ILOGV statement, you are going to get an insane amount of log spam. Every process on the device is going to print a message to logcat for every dalvik instruction that is executed.

If I were doing this, I would take a different approach. I would extract the dex file from the process, using something like ptrace, and then run baksmali on it.

But if you really do want to enable that, it's easy to find where [`ILOGV` is defined](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/vm/mterp/out/InterpC-armv5te-vfp.cpp#132). As you can see, `ILOGV` is only enabled if the `LOG_INSTR` symbol is defined. Another quick search shows a [handy #define statement for `LOG_INSTR`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/vm/mterp/out/InterpC-armv5te-vfp.cpp#81) earlier in the file that is commented out.

It looks like you should be able to uncomment that and recompile dalvik in order to generate the insanely massive amounts of logspam that you seem to want.

Keep in mind that dalvik has [different interpreters](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/vm/mterp/out). The [portable c interpreter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/vm/mterp/out/InterpC-portable.cpp), and [arch specific interpreters](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/vm/mterp/out/InterpC-armv5te-vfp.cpp), etc. So you'll need to be aware of which interpreter is being used on your device, and make sure to modify the correct one -- or just modify all them. E.g. by modifying the common [header.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/vm/mterp/c/header.cpp) and running [rebuild.sh](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-mr2.2-release/vm/mterp/rebuild.sh) to regenerate the various interpreters.

Comment: I put `LOG_INSTR := true` in `buildspec.mk` file and compiled but it did not work. Anyway, I changed every `ILOGV("` by `ALOGD("` and I can now print the code interpreted by the portable C interpreter. However, the code looks like dalvik bytecode, not assembly language code or arm/x86 machine code that I need to print. By the way, I am running an Android emulator with `target_arch=armv7-a` and `host_arch=x86`

Comment: LOG_INSTR := true is going to set LOG_INSTR to true within the make file. That has no effect on any c/c++ code that is then compiled. Like I said, just uncomment the #define LOG_INSTR in the relevant interpreter.